# How can I set the number of the posts on each row in this wordpress grid theme?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, gridview, blogs

I've got this wordpress grid theme:

http://upthemes.com/themes/gallery/

But I can't find a way to make it display just two photos per row.

(I need this to display bigger photos).

I tried to look into the css editor but I havent found anything useful..

(Dont pay attention to the content, Its just a test.)

Thanks for you assistance!

**edit:**

List of resources:

```
Templates
Archives
(archive.php)
Category Template
(category.php)
Comments
(comments.php)
content-gallery.php
content-none.php
content-page.php
content-quote.php
content-single.php
content-status.php
content-video.php
content.php
Footer
(footer.php)
Theme Functions
(functions.php)
Header
(header.php)
Main Index Template
(index.php)
custom-header.php
gallery-slider.php
options.php
Page Template
(page.php)
sidebar-footer.php
Sidebar
(sidebar.php)
Single Post
(single.php)
Tag Template
(tag.php)
Styles
Stylesheet
(style.css)
Visual Editor Stylesheet
(editor-style.css)
```

**Where should I change it?**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Pages have their own individual settings you have to chose from? Go to Page -> Page Options (below the text-editing input) and look around

Comment: I've added a list of the resources that I see there.. which one of them should I open?